# Android Studio suppress warnings

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, lint

Recently updated to Android Studio 3.5 and now my code is full of annoying yellow lines with warning that I would like to suppress.

However, when trying clicking on the yellow bulb and use the solution proposed, it does not work, it just adds a comment-like line that has no effect, example:

When getting this warning:

```
"Use => for short members whose body is a single return statement"
```

Yellow bulb just adds a line above like this:

```
// ignore: prefer_expression_function_bodies
```

Any permanent solution to these annoying warnings in Android Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dart analyzer does this and the `ignore` comment should suppress the warnings. By the way, this should not have anything to do with your Android Studio version.

There are two main ways to suppress specific lints "globally":

- Use `ignore_for_file` comments. This is analogous to `ignore`, but works for the whole file.
  Simply add the following somewhere:

```dart
// ingore_for_file: prefer_expression_function_bodies
```

- Specify exclusions in your `analysis_options.yaml` file. You can always view documentation for all the lints, e.g. for [`prefer_expression_function_bodies`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_expression_function_bodies.html), and any lint can be excluded in your `analysis_options.yaml` file (it should be placed in the same directory as your `pubspec.yaml`):

```
linter:
  rules:
    prefer_expression_function_bodies: false
```

[Learn more](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options).